# A ChangeNotifierProxyProvider was used after being disposed

Tags: flutter, api, retrypolicy

I am retrying an api call if I get 401 response but I am not Abel to call and I am facing exception following is my retry code

```
final client = RetryClient(
      http.Client(),
      retries: 1,
      when: (response) {
        return response.statusCode == 401 ? true : false;
      },
      onRetry: (req, res, retryCount) {
        print('retry started');
        if (retryCount == 0 && res?.statusCode == 401) {
          Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).restoreAccessToken();
          
        }
      },
    );
```

in the above code I am Abel to restore new access token but I am not Abel to retry api call following is my proxy provider I Am guessing error is coming from here

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, ApiCalls>(
            create: (_) => ApiCalls(null),
            update: (context, auth, previous) => ApiCalls(auth.token)),
```

[image]

Comment: Please post more detailed code, with error messages

Comment: I am getting A ApiCalls was used after being disposed when I am retrying the request

Comment: @SankethB.K updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here after a long try I got the solution following code solved the issue I had changed code in change notifier provider

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, ApiCalls>(
            create: (_) => ApiCalls(),
            update: (context, auth, previous) =>
                previous!..updates(auth.token!)),
```

Comment: The `update: (context, auth, previous) => ApiCalls(auth.token)),`  is the cause of the problem, where after creating an object from `ApiCalls` it `disposed` and I don't understand why!

Answer (score 2):

I've tried several and will share what I came up with.

I ran into the same issue mentioned in the question, I'll explain it again now.

This is my ChangeNotifierProxyProvider code:

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<ProfileProvider, SplashProvider>(
          create: (context) => SplashProvider(splashRepo: SplashRepo(), profileProvider: ProfileProvider()),
          update: (context, profileProvider, _) => SplashProvider(splashRepo: SplashRepo(), profileProvider: profileProvider),
        ),
```

And when I execute the `notifyListeners();` function from `SplashProvider`, the same error mentioned in the question pops up

> Unhandled Exception: A SplashProvider was used after being disposed.

So the logical solution is to move the Provider above MaterialApp/Navigator as mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/168#issuecomment-514305799).

However my code is actually written this way! So how does this error appear?
I don't understand why SplashProvider is being disposed? I did not even disposed my current screen yet!

So I've tried the following:

1. change SplashProvider constructor from

```
SplashProvider({
    required this.splashRepo,
    required this.profileProvider,
  })
```

to:

```
SplashProvider({
    required this.splashRepo,
    required this.profileProvider,
  }) {
    debugPrint('SplashProvider constructor');
  }
```

To keep track of the number of objects being created from the same provider
It turned out that more than one instance was created, and this is the output:

```
I/flutter ( 5370): SplashProvider constructor
I/flutter ( 5370): SplashProvider constructor
I/flutter ( 5370): SplashProvider constructor
```

So I modified the constructor by adding `message`:

```
final SplashRepo splashRepo;
  ProfileProvider? profileProvider;
  + final String? message;

  SplashProvider({
    required this.splashRepo,
    this.profileProvider,
    + this.message,
  }) {
    debugPrint('SplashProvider constructor: $message');
  }
```

Then changed `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` by adding `message` to distinguish each of them:

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<ProfileProvider, SplashProvider>(
          create: (context) => SplashProvider(message: 'create', splashRepo: SplashRepo(), profileProvider: ProfileProvider()),
          update: (context, profileProvider, _) => SplashProvider(message: 'update', splashRepo: SplashRepo(), profileProvider: profileProvider),
        ),
```

Then I wrote these two commands into `SplashProvider` to track if the provider was `disposed` or not, and also when `notifyListeners` was called, and for which object in them.

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    debugPrint('SplashProvider disposed...[$message]');
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void notifyListeners() {
    debugPrint('notifyListeners in splash: [$message]');
    super.notifyListeners();
  }
```

And this is the output:

```
...
I/flutter ( 5370): SplashProvider constructor: create
I/flutter ( 5370): SplashProvider constructor: update
I/flutter ( 5370): notifyListeners in splash: [update]
...
I/flutter ( 5370): SplashProvider constructor: update
I/flutter ( 5370): SplashProvider disposed...[update]
I/flutter ( 5370): [ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Build
...
I/flutter ( 5370): notifyListeners in splash: [update]
E/flutter ( 5370): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: A SplashProvider was used after being disposed.
E/flutter ( 5370): Once you have called dispose() on a SplashProvider, it can no longer be used.
...
```

### So it tries to call `notifyListeners` in the updated instance which had disposed already!

then it throws that error

To solve this problem I tried changing the main ChangeNotifierProxyProvider command to:

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<ProfileProvider, SplashProvider>(
          create: // same code...,
          update: (context, profileProvider, prev) => prev!..setProfileProvider(profileProvider),
        ),
```

And surely added this function in `SplashProvider`:

```
void setProfileProvider(ProfileProvider profile){
   this.profileProvider = profile;
  }
```

to set profileProvider.

**Upon trying more than once, the problem was actually solved.**
**1. The error never appears again.**
**2. SplashProvider is not disposed.**
**3. Only one Provider instance is created.**

But I don't know yet if this will affect the other Provider that I passed to SplashProvider and will it pass the same instance or will it create a new instance?
I will experiment and if there is something unexpected I will amend my comment.